# Searching for users by their username in Firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

I am trying to make a search function that queries user by their username from Firebase database, but I want my the function to only return the users with the exact username(letters) that is typed in to the search bar. so lets say if I type Mike into the search bar and tap search, I don't want it to return anything unless there is a user with this exact username(Mike).

I would really appreciate any help to improve my search function from you guys, thanks!

Here is my function:

```
 var REF_USERS = Database.database().reference().child("users")           

 func searchQueryUsers(text: String, completion: @escaping (theUsers) -> Void) {
        REF_USERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshot in
            snapshot.children.forEach({ (sss) in
                let child = sss as! DataSnapshot
                if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                    let user = theUsers.setUser(dict: dict, key: child.key)
                    completion(user)
                }
            })
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
func searchQueryUsers(text: String, completion: @escaping (_ userNames: [String]) -> Void) {

    var userNames: [String] = []

    REF_USERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for item in snapshot.children {

            guard let item = item as? DataSnapshot else {
                break
            }

            //"name" is a key for name in FirebaseDatabese model
            if let dict = item.value as? [String: Any], let name = dict["name"] as? String {
                userNames.append(name)
            }
        }

        completion(userNames)
    })
}
```

As a result, you will have a list of names.

But if you need only 1 name, use:

```
let nameOfFirstUser: String = userNames.first
```

**Why is it better to get the entire list of names?**

In your database, for example, there may be such names: Mike, Michel ...

And if you enter "Mi" in the searchBar, both the first and the second name will match your search query.

Comment: Thank you for your help Maxwell, I will try this out.